# Prevent screen from turning off in lock screen

Tags: display, battery, sleep-wake, screen, lockscreen

Is it possible to keep the screen on 24/7. I have all the sleep settings set to Never but when I lock the MacBook the screen turns off after a few minutes. I need this because I need to have a remote connection sometimes and when the screen turns off in the lock screen it drops the connection.

It is a 2020 MacBook Pro on Big Sur 11.6

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked: System Preferences > Battery > Power Adapter > "Prevent your Mac from automatically sleeping when the display is off" ? While this would allow the display to sleep, it should keep the connection for remote access alive.

Comment: Remote Desktop ought to be able to wake the Mac even if it's asleep. I do this all day, every day with a plethora of remote Macs from my desk. Small example, the middle Mac… been asleep a day or so - https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2SR5.png Wakes in seconds - https://i.stack.imgur.com/baATX.png [the others you see are in  use doing tasks that will keep them awake even if no user is present]

Comment: @KevinGrabher Yes, I have that setting checked.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am using Desktop Central to do remote connections on many different devices. Once I lock the Mac screen and do not move the mouse the screen goes black after about 10 seconds and I'm not able to bring it back up.

Comment: I don't know Desktop Central, nor how it functions, sorry. Did you check with the developers to see how this ought to function in their software?